# how to add key value of same index with another key value of same index in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, algorithm, object, react-hooks

i want to add key value pairs of same index together.

expecting output :

```
[{ 
0:
 ip: "111.11.11.10"
 views: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
1:
 ip: "22.42.22.22"
 views: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
}]
```

instead i am getting :
[image]

my resultDevices data and localStorage data response :
[image]

code i have tried :

let deviceValueLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(DEVICES_LOCALSTORAGE_NAME) || '[]');

const resultDevices = await axios.all(devicesDataViews);

```
const ipFromMultipleDevices = resultDevices.map((d) => d.data?.views);
setDevicesViewsApi(ipFromMultipleDevices);

const deviceValMap = deviceValueLocal.map((d: any) => d.ipAddress);
const deviceIPMap = ipFromMultipleDevices.map((d: any) => d);

const newObject = {
  ip: deviceValMap,
  views: deviceIPMap,
};

console.log(newObject, 'add zero key view to zero key ip');
```

Comment: what does `resultDevices` have as data? also please paste sample `DEVICES_LOCALSTORAGE_NAME` data

Comment: yes, i have edited the post

Answer (score 0):

i did it using :

```
var combined = deviceValMap.map(function (item: any, index: any) {
      return { ip: item, views: deviceIPMap[index] };
    });
```